# Where to store refresh token if not in local storage?

Tags: oauth2

In general it's recommended not to store refresh tokens in local storage. The [Auth0 documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/guides/store-tokens) advises against it.

Even though I am aware of the underlying threats, what I am not aware is if there are any alternatives as to how to store those tokens in order to have persistence within the duration of a user's session when the API server is different than the client. If the tokens are only stored in memory, then the user will have to login every time he closes a tab for example and later on visits the site again.

Finally, I think anyway the refresh token rotation would mitigate the risk of having the tokens stolen. So in the lights of that, the above recommendation doesn't look very valid.

Comment: The refresh token is not supposed to survive user session. If the user logs out (i.e. the session is destroyed), the refresh token becomes invalid. 

Did you mean that refresh token should be persisted between browser/tab closures?

Comment: indeed, i've worded it better

Answer (score 2):

Storing the refresh and access token is in JavaScript memory is generally considered much better than cookies or other browser storage.

You still don't need to worry about asking the user to login every time. The authorisation server (Auth0 in your case) maintains its own session (SSO Session) behind the scenes which is persistent. So it survives even if the user closes the browser.

This means that even if you have "lost" the refresh token stored in memory (e.g. if the user closes the tab), you just need to re-run the authorisation code flow to get new refresh and access tokens (i.e. redirect the user to the authorisation server). This should be silent to the user (i.e. they won't see the login screen) because of the same SSO session that is maintained by the authorisation server would still be active.

Comment: In [oauth2.1-draft](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-parecki-oauth-v2-1-02#section-9.3.1), it states that authorization servers shouldn't (ok, no must not) automatically process auth requests without user interaction. Maybe depending on the authorization server to automatically process those requests is not a futureproof solution?

Comment: How does the server identify the session of the browser if the tokens have been lost?

Comment: Could you please explain why JavaScript memory is generally considered better than cookies or other browser storage for access tokens? If you have malicious JavaScript running (because of XSS), then can't that JavaScript read the memory anyway just as it can the local storage?

Comment: @tturbox, I believe your reference talks about a different thing. It's saying that authorization server should prevent one application from impersonating another app and therefore 'stealing' user consent given to that app. Note that in section 9.3 the spec references redirectUri registration. This should be enough for browser-based apps to ensure client identity, because only the registered domain will be able to receive the Auth Code back (or access token, but you really shouldn't use Implicit Grant anymore).

Comment: @stoft, It's not the server (your app backend) who'll do that, but the Authorization Server. They should all use Secure HttpOnly cookies to securely managed authentication session. So, your app redirects to Auth Server, it sees its own cookies, does authentication / authorization magic, issues new tokens and redirects back to your app.

Comment: @AndrewBate, good question. Actually, not all JS memory can be easily read by a JS code. Local variables cannot be read outside of the function. You can also use closures to make private variables, which only the code inside the closure can access. Smart enough JS code should be able to keep tokens inaccessible to injected code. And you'll also need to do a good Content-Security-Policy, especially to lock the possible sources of service worker scripts, as these can intercept requests.